# form submit done as get when via facebook mobile in-app browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, asp.net-core, mobile, browser

I have a few download links on a web page that use this js function to make a form post that will return a `FileResult` from the server:

```
function downloadFile() {
    var $form = $('<form method="post"/>').attr('action', 'downloadFileUrl').appendTo('body');

    $form.append("<input type='hidden' name='" + paramx + "' value='" + valx + "'/>");
    ...

    $form.submit();
    $form.remove();
}
```

and it works on desktop, on mobile browser apps,

**except** when you get to the page by clicking from the **facebook mobile app (when there's no address bar)**,

instead of a `POST` a `GET` request is done.

anybody faced this problem before, is there a known solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like facebook in-app browser will do the `post` and after without waiting for the result will switch/go to the default browser app with the `url` being what was in the `form` `action` attribute,

so knowing that I've added the necessary parameters to the form action

`<form action="url?parm1=val1"...`

and I've created a page for this `url` where I read the `param1` and repeat the action.